# Gulpfile is not being recognized

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

The documentation states that gulp and jake files should be autodetected. I have a gulpfile.js in the root of my opened folder, but it is not being autodetected and listed in the task list when I try and run a task. Am I missing something?

Comment: have you installed gulp both global & locally?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that but no luck.

Comment: I have the same issue, gulp installed locally + globally, gruntfile.js in root but Code does not show any of the tasks. :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying and what is the error message?

Comment: I'm opening a folder with my project inside. The gulp file is in the root directory. I open the command pallette, type in Task, and the only task I see is the default tsc one. There is no error, it just doesn't show my tasks from the gulp file.

Answer (score 9):

1. `gulpfile.js` in the root
2. `npm install -g gulp` :gulp install globally
3. `npm install gulp` : gulp install locally to your dev folder
4. You need a custom `tasks.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "gulp",
       "isShellCommand": true,
       "args": [
           "--no-color"
       ],
       "tasks": []
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, so the trick is figuring out what you are missing.

All I have is:

- gulpfile.js in the root
- gulp install globally (`npm install -g gulp`)
- `npm install` has been run locally and includes gulp
- a `tasks.json` file with a command set to `gulp`

I then can open the palette and type `task mytaskname` and it works

**UPDATE:** Without the `tasks.json` file with a gulp command, vs code does not pick them up for me either.

Comment: What I did to avoid installing gulp globally is to place a `gulp.cmd` in the root of my workspace that invokes a local gulp installation: `node  "%~dp0\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js" %*`

Comment: having gulp globally is kinda valuable tho, as the CLI is needed in many cases.

Comment: I have the same issue, gulpfile.js in root with 2 tasks, gulp installed locally and globally, tasks run fine from root project command line but code doesn't want to detect the tasks.

Comment: not a solution, but I suspect this is some sort of bug related to the tasks.json. When VSCode was NOT detecting my gulpfile.js I had a build task running tsc to compile my typescript. I was playing around with the tasks.json to see if I could get it to run gulp and suddenly it started showing tasks from my gulpfile. I don't know why but it seems that having the tsc command in tasks.json messes up gulpfile task detection?

Comment: Yeah I've followed all those steps on different test projects and it detects fine, but for some reason in my main application it doesn't detect any tasks, except for the default tsc task. I tried removing that task but it still doesn't detect.

Comment: I had the same problem, solved it by:   1. install gulp globally `npm install -g gulp`.       2. install gulp locally under dev: 'npm install --save-dev gulp'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks miked for pointing into the right direction. Here is an explanation how VSCode works today:

If a tasks.json file exists and it defines a task runner (e.g. command property) that has no auto detection support (e.g. tsc) then the tasks.json has preference over auto detection.

If it list a command that has auto detection (e.g. gulp and jake) then it merges the tasks defined in tasks.json with the once auto detected.

In general VSCode only supports one task runner integration right now. So if you use both gulp and grunt VSCode can either integrate with Grunt or Gulp right now.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code with ( tasks.json - version 2.0.0 ). Included gulp task runner. "Ctrl + Shift + B" -> execute tasks in gulpfile.js -> open html file with Chrome browser.

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Gulp",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gulp",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always"
        }
    },
    {
        "taskName": "Chrome",
        "type": "process",
        "command": "chrome.exe",
        "windows": {
            "command": "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
        },
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to AlphaPage and John Papa' answers (I don't have enough rep to add a comment), if you install gulp globally (`npm install gulp -g`), and you have a `gulpfile.js` in the root, when you:

1. Open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. Type `Tasks` and click on **Configure Task Runner**

then the `tasks.json` as listed by Alphapage will be automatically created **if it does not already exist**. And the gulp tasks will be automatically detected.